# Suppose Y is a random vairable with $E(|Y|^\alpha)<\infty$ for some $\alpha > 0$, Then $E(|Y|^\beta)<\infty$ for $0\leq \beta \leq \alpha$

Tags: probability, random-variables, jensen-inequality

During my studies for intro. to probability (undergrad) we learned about Jensen's inequality. The lecturer showed as the following theorem during one of our lectures:

> Suppose $Y$ is a random variable with $E(|Y|^\alpha)<\infty$ for some $\alpha > 0$, Then $E(|Y|^\beta)<\infty$ for $0\leq \beta \leq \alpha$

I'm attempting to prove this theorem.
I've tried using the definition of expectation and Jensen's inequality, by showing that the series converges (I've also tried absolute convergence).
But I'm not sure which convex function I should choose, and all of my attempts were dead ends.

Any suggestions will be very helpful.

Comment: First you could solve the cases where $\beta = 0$ or $\beta = \alpha$ as they're trivial. Note that the function $f(x) = x^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}$ is convex by the second derivative test. Could you fit this into the context of Jensen's inequality?

Comment: I can see it now! thank you :)

Comment: You really don't need Jensen for this.  Just note that $|y|^\beta \le 1 + |y|^\alpha$ (consider the two cases $|y| \le 1$ and $|y| > 1$).